# jQuery button not being added

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am making changes on this WordPress site http://victoriafalls24.com/ and for some reason, the button that I am trying to add on the mobile menu is not being added.

I added this on the child theme:

```
$(document).ready(function(){      
  $('ul.mobile-nav').addClass('mobile-design');
  $('li.menu-item-has-children').addClass('mobile-design');
  $('<button type="button" class="new-button">Click Me!</button>').insertAfter('ul.mobile-menu #nav-menu-item-24105 > a');      
});
```

The class mobile-design was added, but not the button.

Please help.

Comment: @Kartikeya Khosla.Nothing is displayed.I actualy tried to alert any random text and nothing happens.

Comment: Did you check your console?

Comment: Everything checked. Well I just found that it has got something to do with the child theme.  Cause I added  the same code in  the parent theme and it  is working.Why,I don't know.

Comment: The button is in your DOM, and it's visible.

Comment: @Fralec.It is yes because I managed to add it through the parent theme